# VBScript - Multiple Issues

Tags: vbscript

So I've been thrown in the deep end of the shark tank without even my arm floaters and I don't know how to swim (Translation - I don't know VBS).

So I find myself here because I keep hitting my scripts with the two sticks I have it still doesn't work.  When I fix one issue another appears and when I fix that one the other returns (feel like I'm chasing my tail).

So below is the latest iteration of my code (I keep moving crap around thinking it might magically work).

```
'---- Set Constant for Reading
Const ForReading = 1

'----- Define at the Variables for the scripts
    Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


'------ Path for File below is Explicit (meaning you need to enter the  complete path)
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\users\me\documents\Small- ComputerList.txt", ForReading)



'---- Begin Loop for reading the Array 
 Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream
   strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline
  arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , ",")

' -------  strComputer = "usms-w-ksd68598"  Commented out from original script
' -------  Reading from the Array 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & arrServiceList(0) & "\root\cimv2")

' ------- Running the Command to find all the printers 
Set colPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Printer")

    For Each objPrinter in colPrinters 
        objDictionary.RemoveAll
        objDictionary.Add objPrinter.PortName, objPrinter.PortName
    Next

' ------  Running the Command to find all the TCP/IP Printer Ports
Set colPorts = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort")
    For Each objPort in colPorts
        If objDictionary.Exists(objPort.Name) Then
            strUsedPorts = strUsedPorts & _
            objDictionary.Item(objPort.Name) & VbCrLf
    Else
        strFreePorts = strFreePorts & objPort.Name & vbCrLf
    End If

Next

'----- Printing out the Results to the screen

For i = 1 to Ubound(arrServiceList)
    & arrServiceList(i)
  Next
 Loop

Wscript.Echo "System Name: " & arrServiceList(0)
Wscript.Echo "The following ports are in use for: " & VbCrLf & strUsedPorts 
Wscript.Echo "The following ports are not used for: " & VbCrLf & strFreePorts
```

If my crazy ducted taped scripts make no sense please don't be shocked.  I've been stuck in a cave hitting the keyboard with two sticks and this is the result I've come up with.  Not too bad for a caveman but it still doesn't work.

Any help, assistance, advice, comment, jokes, sarcasm, ranting appreciated.   Any trolling will be swiftly dealt with a big mallet over the head.

Thank you,

Ed Medina

Comment: What is your script intending to achieve? That might help us get a working answer...

Comment: Hey Big Chris - Thanks for the question.  So the Script is supposed to read from a Text File into an array then read from the array (the computer name) and run the command to list all of the printer ports (in use and not in use).

Comment: Hi there.  So what's not working?  What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Hey Roryap - So it depends on what I do and what the error is.  I get the following errors. Type Mismatched, Statement expected (compliation Error).  Obviously, I have no clue what I'm doing. 

What I am trying to do is read from a file (text) and run the command to list the unused ports.  I can run the script to read from a file fine and I can run the script to list the ports from a single computer (entering the name of the computer into the string).   

But when I try to combine the two I fail miserably.

Answer (score 0):

Lo and behold the gods of code have shine their light upon my path and provided me with an answer.

Anyway, Thanks to Big Chris and Mr. Roryap for their questions.  I want to also thank the Academy, all of my fellow coders, my mom, coffee, the mailman, my wife, my cat and all the little people.

Here is a code that will work which will read from a file in your Temp Folder (file is named Computers.txt) and then against that file it will run and test to find all the printers ports in that computer in your Domain (Network).

The output is a simple Echo out giving it to you in the window.  I just kept hitting the keyboard with my two sticks in my dark, smelly cave and out came out the code.

The only caveat is that if you have a wrong computer name or a computer turned off the script will fail at that point and won't continue (yeah, yeah, working on it).

```
'---- Set Constant for Reading
 Const ForReading = 1

 '----- Define at the Variables for the scripts
  Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


   '------ Path for File below is Explicit (meaning you need to enter   the complete path)
   Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\Temp\Computers.txt", ForReading)



     '---- Begin Loop for reading the Array 
     Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

     strComputer = objFile.ReadLine

' -------  Reading from the Array 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    ' ------- Running the Command to find all the printers 
    Set colPrinters =  objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_Printer")

      For Each objPrinter in colPrinters 
         objDictionary.RemoveAll
          objDictionary.Add objPrinter.PortName, objPrinter.PortName
      Next

  ' ------  Running the Command to find all the TCP/IP Printer Ports
  Set colPorts = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
      ("Select * from Win32_TCPIPPrinterPort")
      For Each objPort in colPorts
          If objDictionary.Exists(objPort.Name) Then
              strUsedPorts = strUsedPorts & _
            objDictionary.Item(objPort.Name) & VbCrLf
      Else
          strFreePorts = strFreePorts & objPort.Name & vbCrLf
      End If

  Next

     '---- Output to Screen 
   Wscript.Echo "System Name: " & strComputer
   Wscript.Echo "The following ports are in use for: " & VbCrLf & strUsedPorts 
  Wscript.Echo "The following ports are not used for: " & VbCrLf & strFreePorts


Loop
```

Thank you. 
BTW if anyone know how to throw an error and keep working give feel free to post.  Thanks again everyone.

Comment: I think `objDictionary.RemoveAll` should be outside the `For Each objPrinters` loop body, otherwise you will only ever have the last printed portname stored